# SharePoint 2013 - Service Pack 1: Language Pack is missing

Tags: 2013, service-pack, psconfig

Today I wanted to update my SharePoint 2013 with SP 1.

I´m using 2 WFE with SharePoint 2013 English and a German Language Pack.
The Language Pack is installed on both SharePoint Server.

**My installation steps:**

1. Install SP 1 on both Servers - OK
2. PSConfig WFE 1 - OK
3. PSconfig WFE 2 - OK
4. Install Language Pack SP 1 on both Servers - OK
5. PSConfig WFE 1 - Error
   The following is missing on Server 1 (Yes only Server 1)
   The Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Language Pack (KB2880554) 64-Bit Edition

I tried already "Get-SPProduct -Local".

So I end up with PSConfig and "–cmd installcheck – noinstallcheck". But this is not really a solution...

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a read on this link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/03/11/sharepoint-2013-language-pack-sp1-quot-slipstream-quot-installations-are-now-available.aspx

Comment: i would recommend, even though you install the LPs on both server and PSconfig complaining its missing, try to restart the server, and also try to to re install the Language Packs, some time re running the setup fix the issue.